# Is there a good replacement for PhoneApplicationService.State in Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal App)?

Tags: win-universal-app

I'm porting a Windows Phone 8.0 app to a universal store app. I used the state dictionary frequently to pass state info between pages. I know the new navigation service has support for a parameter, but I was looking for something that can store state outside the scope of the page. Does anyone know the "universal app way" of keeping state information in the scope of the app?

Comment: For now I'm storing the state in isolated storage and loading it again. Not sure if this is the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement is the SuspensionManager.

You can use SuspensionManager.SessionState instead of PhoneApplicationService.Current.State

Answer (score 1):

[check this blog](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/10/passing-object-to-wp-navigation-service.html).

you can pass object directly to Navigate function.

Comment: This still doesn't help me in the case where the page requesting navigation doesn't have a reference to the object needing to be communicated, maybe it is on a previous instance of the page. Also, the blog you pointed me to isn't about Universal Apps, it's about wp silverlight apps.