# Windows Phone 8.1 - How to handle Hardware back button GoBack with a Parameter back to the previous page

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 application.

On a page when the user hits the hardware back button I want to Navigate back but also want to send a parameter to the previous page. But GoBack function doesn't take any parameter. How do I pass a parameter back so that the previous page?

This is how I have handled Hardware back button currently

In my View Constructor

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

The event handler

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        rootFrame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not just use PhoneApplicationService.Current.State to store all your values across your pages?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware That was supported only in Windows Phone Silverlight. Not supported in WinRT Universal Windows Phone 8.1 applications. People recommend to use Navigation parameter for the same. See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749975/is-there-a-good-replacement-for-phoneapplicationservice-state-in-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem using singleton pattern where i created a controller class seen by all the mobile pages and through it i passes messages through them.
Hope this answer helps you

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension. Here, some sample code would be more helpful.

Comment: @HodaGharieb - Yes as reporter mentioned could you please provide some sample code as this approach would mean my entire page-page communication for phone happens through this messaging singleton class.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to handle this properly depending on the architecture of your app/project. Here are a couple of possible solutions:

1 - public (static) property object on App.xaml.cs. This way you can set the object from anywhere, and read it from anywhere.

```
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    ............

    public static SomeType SomeObjectIPreferToShareAcrossApp { get; set; }

    ............
}
```

Then there's your backpressed handler:

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        App.SomeObjectIPreferToShareAcrossApp = this.someObjectIHaveOnlyOnThisPage;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Then when you navigate to a page, check if that object is set, read it, and reset it.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        if (App.SomeObjectIPreferToShareAcrossApp != null)
        {
            // yay, do something :)
            App.SomeObjectIPreferToShareAcrossApp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure some people would object to this way of sharing because it may be error-prone and ugly.

2 - Some sort of [event aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) implementation, meaning that you publish/send a certain message or an object from a publisher to all of the subscribers.

3 - Shared ViewModel instances

There are other ways, but again - it depends on the architecture of your project/app.

Comment: The shared object looks interesting. 
I am trying to use the SharedViewModel instances.
In this case the ViewModel needs to be passed as a parameter in NavigationService to the next page and passed back to the first page when the user presses back. But in back I can't pass the ViewModel back hence will lose the context in the MainPage.
Are you trying to mention shared ViewModel instances in a different way?

Comment: @vivekp no, I don't think you need to pass VMs around. MVVM Light framework, for example, has a singleton ViewModelLocator class which keeps references to all the VMs in your app, which means you can access them from anywhere you like. You can even bind both of your pages to the same ViewModel if they are tightly coupled, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with something like:

```
  using System;

namespace SimpleMVVM.Model
{  
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID
        {
            get; 
            set;   
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Phone
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can assign/get these through your pages, rather than sending variables between pages.

Comment: Who will hold the objects of these classes? Won't they be destroyed when you navigate your pages?

Comment: When I did my project (~a year ago) I think I put them into the global class (although this works for small strings/ints/etc, I would advise against placing too many variables there) :P But if you are only needing one or two variables sent, it wouldn't be too bad!

Answer (score 0):

You must control to `e.Handled` like this:

```
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack && !e.Handled)
        {
            rootFrame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

If you don't control to `e.Handled`, `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event continue to back stack deep.